# Metric Dimension of Lattice Graph

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, metric-spaces

I am sorry, I am beginner in this course about metric dimension of graph. I have a problem to determine metric dimension of lattice on graph theory. When I choose resolving set with $2,3,4,5$ vertices, then there are other vertices have same coordinates. It means metric dimension is greater than 5. Unfortunately, I can't check anymore for $6,7,...,36$ vertices. Any ideas or any lemmas that can help me to prove or determine the metric dimension of picture below? Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: I can get a metric on 4 points for your diagram. I haven't tried three.

Comment: The point of the metric dimension (say $m$) is that it's the minimum number of points that will produce a metric, not that any such $m$ points will - so what point sets have you tried?

Comment: The metric dimension is three; I suggest you try again to look for a resolving set of size $3$.

Comment: @Joffan Yeah, thank you very much. I made a mistake when choosing points for resolving set. Now, I choose $3$ points in the lower left corner, upper left corner, and upper right corner. I calculate coordinates of every points except 3 points above. I think it's a resolving set.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Yes, I tried again and found the metric dimension is 3. Thank you for your correction.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an answer so for completeness.

The metric dimension is $3$. Any set of three corner points will be a resolving set, which can be seen by writing out the triple of distances for each point on the grid.

Furthermore, no pair of points is a resolving set. For any pair of points $\{x,y\}$ with distance $d$, you show there will exist two points whose distances to $x$ and $y$ are the same:

- If $x$ and $y$ are on the same diagonal (meaning the slope of the line connecting there centers is $\pm 1$), then there exist two points whose distances to $x$ and $y$ are both $d$.
- If $x$ and $y$ are adjacent, there will exist two points whose distances to $x$ and $y$ are both $1$.
- In all other cases, there will exist two points whose distances to $x$ is  $1$ and whose distance to $y$ is $d-1$.

Comment: Good to emphasize the "proving minimality" side, which is part of why finding metric dimension for a general graph is hard, +1

Comment: Mike, a typesetting trick I use (& you might like) for referring to $d{-}1$ more as a value rather than a calculation is `$d{-}1$` to "despace" the minus sign.